# What is wrong with this code? Swift optionals

Tags: ios, swift

What is wrong with this code?

```
        if documentArray != nil { rowCount = documentArray?.count } else { rowCount = 1 }
```

Xcode tells me I need to add an ! to the end of count, then when I add it it tells me I need to delete it. This makes no sense to me. I'm ready checking if the NSArray exists so if it does then it should have a count. All this optional crap is really starting to piss me off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try rowCount = documentArray!.count. The error messages in Swift are quite annoying, and sometimes completely baffling. Hopefully, they will be improved at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode is mad because you are using optional chaining with documentArray?.count. You should use documentArray!.count to force unwrap the value.

Another approach, conditional binding is sometimes an easier way to not have to worry about these sorts of things.

```
if let documentArray = documentArray {
    rowCount = documentArray.count
} else {
    rowCount = 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was made more confusing by the fact Xcode was autofilling the '?' on documentArray by itself. I see the object?.property thing filled in a lot by Xcode and I'm not even sure what this means. I assumed that it was checking for the presence of the object and if it was 'nil' then 'nil' would be returned. I'm guessing now I am wrong about this.

Comment: I'd say generally it's safer to return an optional than force unwrap an optional, all other things being equal, if that makes any sense. That's why they do that I guess? Though in your case was rowCount an optional?

Comment: You can also use the nil coalescing operator.  `rowCount = documentArray?.count ?? 1`

Comment: @AdamRussell: Force unwrapping an optional inside an `if` block that checks the optional is completely safe.